# Как пропустить MsgBox и перейти к странице удаления сразу?

Tags: inno-setup

При нажатии на unins000.exe появляется такое окно, после нажатия на кнопку Да (OK) появляется форма удаления. Как можно убрать, пропустить это окно и что-бы сразу появлялась страница удаления.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После удаления программы появляется такое окно, можно ли его тоже отключить.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]